# Android Expandable List View Group Indicator

Tags: android, view, alignment

I am working on an android app and using the ExpandableListView in an activity. Problem is that the default icon of the group indicator of this ExpandableList is not centrally aligned vertically(it's more towards the top). Is there anyway I can change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I just added an empty textbox in the layout just above the rest of the group items. And increased it's padding to "10dp". It's still a workaround but at least it worked and now the group indicator is sort of in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use the  setIndictorBounds. may be solve the proble

```
ExpandableListViewobject.setIndicatorBounds(5, 45);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the default indicator to null and inflate your own layout. That way you have total control of your assets and you can easily position it to the right of the row as well.